# Crop Captured RAW Photo and save to file iOS

Tags: ios, core-image, avcapture

Im having a really hard time finding any way to crop my captured RAW image before I send it up to the server. Im using NSURLSession and background upload so I need the image to be written to a file.

Im grabbing the RAW image data as NSData using AVCapturePhoto's `fileDataRepresentation` method. From there I am able to get a CIImage using CIFilter's RAW compatibility but I cant seem to find a way to go back to either NSData or writing the updated image directly to a file.

Note: 
Unfortunately I cant convert to Jpeg or PNG. My specific application requires that I have as few losses as possible and stick with the RAW data. The resultant file should be convertible to the .dng extension just as the raw result from `fileDataRepresentation` is.

Comment: You are unable to crop image right.?

Comment: There is no such thing as a cropped raw photo, only a jpeg (or similar) can be cropped

Comment: Per the duplicate answer: turning a RAW file into a displayable image is like using some ingredients to bake a cake. To extend that analogy, you can't un-bake a slice of cake, nor does choosing a subset of ingredients get you a recipe for a slice. There are some uses of the DNG format that let you save post-editing instructions as metadata alongside the RAW data — that is, it tells other software which slice to cut after baking the whole cake — but there aren't any Apple APIs for such so you're limited to working directly with the Adobe DNG format or other tools.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help guys.